# The view shows <%=Id%> instead of the actual value

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm new to ASP.NET MVC and are trying to display data in a view, but the instructions are shown instead of the data.

My CustomerModel Class;

```
public class CustomerModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Nic { get; set; }
}
```

The below is Customercontroller

```
public class CustomerController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index(CustomerModel Customerobj)
    {
        Customerobj.Id = 1;
        Customerobj.FirstName = "Qaiser";
        Customerobj.LastName = "Abbas";
        Customerobj.Nic = "61101";
        return View(Customerobj);
    }
}
```

The Customer View is

```
@model SmartMinds.Models.CustomerModel
<div>
    The Id of Customer is : <%=Id%>
    The First Name of Customer is:<%CustomerModel.FirstName%>
    The Last Name of Customer is:<%CustomerModel.LastName%>
    The  Nic of Customer is:<%CustomerModel.Nic%>
</div>
```

OutPut is

```
The Id of Customer is : <%=Id%>
The First Name of Customer is:<%CustomerModel.FirstName%>
The Last Name of Customer is:<%CustomerModel.LastName%> 
The Nic of Customer is:<%CustomerModel.Nic%>
```

it does not show the real values

Comment: Your code needs to be indented. Select code and press `{}` button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to supply action arguments when the view sends data (or when you want to get info from the query string), not when you just want to display data.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    CustomerModel Customerobj = new CustomerModel();
    Customerobj.Id = 1;
    Customerobj.FirstName = "Qaiser";
    Customerobj.LastName = "Abbas";
    Customerobj.Nic = "61101";

    return View(Customerobj);
}
```

In the view you need to use razor syntax as this:

```
<div>
    The Id of Customer is : @Model.Id
    The First Name of Customer is: @Model.FirstName
    The Last Name of Customer is: @Model.LastName
    The  Nic of Customer is: @Model.Nic
</div>
```

Comment: Try to format the code and explain why you wrote the code next time.

Comment: @jgauffin thanks for editing on my behalf from next time I would explain it for sure..

Comment: Thanks alot dear I got correct output with your help.

Comment: @Qaiser you are welcome :).please mark it as answer if it has helped you

Comment: Thanks alot dear I got correct output with your solution

Answer (score 0):

When using razor view, you need to use @ and you get the model by using @Model

```
<div>

The Id of Customer is : @Model.Id

The First Name of Customer is:@Model.FirstName

The Last Name of Customer is:@Model.LastName

The  Nic of Customer is:@Model.Nic

</div>
```